# Не работает плагин Quick chat. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин, chat

**wordpress v4.5.2, quick chat v4.13**

проблема в том, что сам плагин отображается на странице но, сообщения не отсылаются и смайлы не активны. При все этом в админке(админская команата) чат работает полноценно

[image: на изображении сам плагин, по нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит]

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[quick-chat height="200" room="default" userlist="1" userlist_position="left" smilies="1" send_button="1" loggedin_visible="1" guests_visible="1" avatars="0" counter="1"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Ставить более раннею версию wordpress'а пробовали, без изменений.

Comment: вызовы `wp_head();` и `wp_footer();` на проблемной странице присутствуют?

Comment: @alenkins, да, присутствуют.

Comment: `<?php wp_head();
echo do_shortcode( '[quick-chat height="200" room="default" userlist="1" userlist_position="left" smilies="1" send_button="1" loggedin_visible="1" guests_visible="1" avatars="0" counter="1"]' );
wp_footer(); ?>` - это минимальный код, с которым у меня заработал ваш плагин для авторизованных и неавторизованных пользователей на последней версии WP

Comment: @alenkins Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    wp_head();
    echo do_shortcode('[quick-chat height="200" room="default" userlist="1" userlist_position="left" smilies="1" send_button="1" loggedin_visible="1" guests_visible="1" avatars="0" counter="1"]');
    wp_footer();
?>
```

это минимальный код в шаблоне `single.php`, с которым у меня заработал ваш плагин для авторизованных и неавторизованных пользователей на последней "чистой" версии WP (без других установленных плагинов)